# Symfony: How to use a form filter with an field that does not exist in an entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a custom field along in a search that does not map to any column in the database.

For example I want to check if a users profile is complete or incomplete and filter on that. I want to pass along a "status" in the form post and depending on what the value is it will search on specific columns (different depending on the user type).

I have tried doing this:

```
 $profile_status = "";
 if($request->query->get("item_filter")['status']){
    $profile_status = $request->query->get("item_filter")['status'];
    $request->query->remove("item_filter")['status'];
 }
```

However it appears that it removes all of my other data that comes along with the form.

This is how I built the form field in the form_filter class

```
$builder->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
    'expanded' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'choices'  => [
        'Filter by Status' => '',
        'Profile Complete' => 'complete',
        'Profile Incomplete' => 'incomplete'
    ]
]);
```

This is how I'm querying the db:

```
$filterBuilder = $this->educatorUserRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
$filterBuilder->andWhere('u.deleted = 0');
$filterBuilder->addOrderBy('u.firstName', 'ASC');

if($user->isSiteAdmin()) {
    $filterBuilder->where('u.site = :site')
        ->setParameter('site', $user->getSite());
}

if($profile_status == 'complete'){
    $filterBuilder->andWhere('u.briefBio IS NOT NULL');
} elseif($profile_status == 'incomplete') {
    $filterBuilder->andWhere('u.briefBio IS NULL');
}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // build the query from the given form object
    $this->filterBuilder->addFilterConditions($form, $filterBuilder);
}

$filterQuery = $filterBuilder->getQuery();
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: I hope you understand that `$request->query->remove('item_filter')['status']` is not making any sense, specifically the `['status']` which will try to access the `status` index of the return value of `...->remove('item_filter')`. I hope this answers your question. Otherwise, I'm too confused by slightly chaotic question.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi, yeah I wasn't entirely sure how to go about that. I was wanting to remove that item from the parameter list like you would a standard array or session item but wasn't having any luck there. The answer below did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the method `addFilterConditions` in your code, I believe you are using [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle).

I never used that bundle, but you can try the following approach:

1- Use [ChoiceFilterType](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/provided-types.md) instead of `ChoiceType` when defining the form fields.

2- The bundle itself offers a way to [disable filtering for one field](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/working-with-the-bundle.md#c-disable-filtering-for-one-field) by setting `'apply_filter' => false`.

3- Set the form field as `mapped => false`.

Your code for form definition will look like this:

```
$builder->add('status', ChoiceFilterType::class, [
    'apply_filter' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'expanded' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'choices'  => [
        'Filter by Status' => '',
        'Profile Complete' => 'complete',
        'Profile Incomplete' => 'incomplete'
    ]
]);
```

4- Drop this piece of code:

```
 $profile_status = "";
 if($request->query->get("item_filter")['status']){
    $profile_status = $request->query->get("item_filter")['status'];
    $request->query->remove("item_filter")['status'];
 }
```

5- Change the code in your controller to look like bellow. This way you will be using the unmapped field `status` to filter by `briefBio`

```
$filterBuilder = $this->educatorUserRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
$filterBuilder->andWhere('u.deleted = 0');
$filterBuilder->addOrderBy('u.firstName', 'ASC');

if($user->isSiteAdmin()) {
    $filterBuilder->where('u.site = :site')
        ->setParameter('site', $user->getSite());
}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if($form->get('status')->getData() == 'complete') {
        $filterBuilder->andWhere('u.briefBio IS NOT NULL');
    } elseif($form->get('status')->getData() == 'incomplete') {
        $filterBuilder->andWhere('u.briefBio IS NULL');
    }

    // build the query from the given form object
    $this->filterBuilder->addFilterConditions($form, $filterBuilder);
}

$filterQuery = $filterBuilder->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Caconde this did what I wanted. The only thing I needed to was change ```$builder->add('status', ChoiceFilterType::class, [``` to ```$builder->add('status', Filters\ChoiceFilterType::class, [```